# What eventTypes does ReactJS (ReactTestUtils) understand?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the `reactjs` [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#simulate) for `Simulate`:

> Simulate has a method for every event that React understands.

I am pretty new to `ReactJS` so I am not sure what event types does reactjs understands. I assume it is the event types listed in Mozilla's Developer Network?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not all of them but most of them:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html

Beware of the JSX syntax :)

Comment: And beware it might not behave like the native event.
Eg. onChange event for eg on `input[type=text]` is called when you're typing.